# How to add columns to Pandas DataFrame with minute of the day, month, year using time stamp from other column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe containing various data, including a column from Linux Timestamp. For further analysis, I need to extract the minutes of each period (hour minute number, day minute number, week minute number, month minute number, year minute number) from the Linux Timestamp column.

I have:

```
TimeStamp   var1   var2
1659494100  5.22   6.34
1659494160  4.33   7.33
1659494220  5.46   7.21
1659494280  4.33   4.51
1659494340  6.45   5.67
...
```

I need to have:

```
TimeStamp   var1   var2   minute_of_hour   minute_of_day   minute_of_week   minute_of_month   minute_of_year
1659494100  5.22   6.34         35              155             3035              3035            308315
1659494160  4.33   7.33         36              156             3036              3036            308316
1659494220  5.46   7.21         37              157             3037              3037            308317
1659494280  4.33   4.51         38              158             3038              3038            308318
1659494340  6.45   5.67         39              159             3039              3039            308319
```

I have a large table and using loops is not an option. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# Your dataframe here:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Timestamp": [1659494100, 1659494160, 1659494220, 1659494280, 1659494340],
    "var1": [5.22, 4.33, 5.46, 4.33, 6.45],
    "var2": [6.34, 7.33, 7.21, 4.51, 5.67]
})

timestamps = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], unit="s")

freqs = {
    "hour": "H",
    "day": "D",
    "week": "W",
    "month": "M",
    "year": "Y"
}

for name, freq in freqs.items():
    df[f"minute_of_{name}"] = (
        timestamps - timestamps.dt.to_period(freq).dt.start_time
    ) // pd.Timedelta("1Min")
```

Output:

```
    Timestamp  var1  var2  minute_of_hour  minute_of_day  minute_of_week  \
0  1659494100  5.22  6.34              35            155            3035   
1  1659494160  4.33  7.33              36            156            3036   
2  1659494220  5.46  7.21              37            157            3037   
3  1659494280  4.33  4.51              38            158            3038   
4  1659494340  6.45  5.67              39            159            3039   

   minute_of_month  minute_of_year  
0             3035          308315  
1             3036          308316  
2             3037          308317  
3             3038          308318  
4             3039          308319
```

Note that some columns can be calculated more directly, but this method makes the code consistent for all frequencies.